# Using React State, how can I swap items in an array to an item in another array?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

here is an example of my code in which for the swap I made a cut function.

this works fine, and deletes the object in the array + stores it in "store"

but when I try to paste it into another array, it pastes it three times.

alll code in 1:

```
let list = [[{comment:""}]]

function reducer(listState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "removeBox":
      listState[action.index].splice(action.NextIndex, 1);
      return listState.slice();
    case "pasteBox":
      console.log(action.store);
      // console.log("store is")
      let copy = [...listState];
      copy[action.index].splice(action.NextIndex, 0, action.store);
      return copy;
    default:
      throw new Error();

      function Trello(props) {
        let [store, setStore] = useState();

        return (
          <div>
            {listState.map((data, index) => (
              <Paper key={index}>
                {data.map((input, NextIndex) => (
                  <div key={NextIndex}>
                    <Button
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        // console.log("123")
                        listDispatch({
                          type: "pasteBox",
                          NextIndex,
                          index,
                          store,
                        });
                      }}
                    >
                      paste Box
                    </Button>
                    <Button
                      onClick={(e) => {
                        // console.log("123")
                        listDispatch({
                          type: "pasteBox",
                          NextIndex,
                          index,
                          store,
                        });
                      }}
                    >
                      paste Box
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </Paper>
            ))}
          </div>
        );
      }
  }
}
```

The problem I have is specifically here:

```
console.log(action.store);
     let copy = [...listState]
        copy[action.index].splice(action.NextIndex, 0, action.store);
      return copy;
```

Whilst if I put only a console.log of action.store it accurately shows the store and only runs once, if I have all this code, then it runs three times.
What is the correct way to do this, so that it specifically only runs once.

## here is the sandy mc boxykins

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-sid-wdn0h?file=/src/App.js

Comment: If you return copy without doing the splice, does the code still fire 3 times? Also you could replace 'let copy' with a const and use filter instead of splice (but I don't think that will fix your problem)

Comment: no, the splice specifically the part making it repeat three times, if i remove the line then the console.log bits will only appear once, if it is there then it will appear three times.

Comment: try changing the code to use filter, that way you can 'copy' can be a const and shouldn't trigger change detection multiple time

Comment: It could have been a const anyway and that seems to have fixed it. I was unaware of the difference between const and let causing such problems.